# Unable to receive file contents on server during upload 

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page in which I have a file input field from which I browse a csv file and then upload it on server. I am using method = "POST" and ENCTYPE='multipart/form-data' in the form in which this file input field is present.

On the servlet side(in the application's servlet) I am making use of apache's common file upload API-ServletFileUpload API. After getting the FileItem list from the method parseRequest(request) of this API I am unable to get the file name and its content by using the methods getName(), getString() of FileItem API.

Needed to know what am I doing wrong or any modifications in my approach that will make my application to work. Any pointers regarding this will be helpful.

Thanks in advance!!

Also tried the following code in the doPost method of application's main servlet:-

`Enumeration enumAttrib = request.getAttributeNames();

```
    while(enumAttrib.hasMoreElements()) {
        String attribName = (String)(enumAttrib.nextElement());
        System.out.println("DEBUG:---------AttribName = " + attribName);
        System.out.println("DEBUG:---------AttribValue=" + request.getAttribute(attribName));
    }`
```

The output that got printed was:

```
DEBUG:---------AttribName = weblogic.servlet.network_channel.port
DEBUG:---------AttribValue=9703
```

Don't know whether the request parameter should return only this or other attributes also.

Also tried following code:

```
if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {

        System.out.println("Inside ApplicationMainServlet request is multipart ");

        // Create a factory for disk-based file items
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        try
        {
            // Parse the request

            List /* FileItem */items = upload.parseReques(request);

            // Process the uploaded items

            Iterator iter = items.iterator();

            while (iter.hasNext())
            {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                String name = item.getFieldName();

                System.out.println("ApplicationMainServlet name: "+item.getFieldName() + ", val: "+item.getString() );

                if (!item.isFormField())
                {  
                    //Item is a file

                try{

                    InputStream is = item.getInputStream();

                    InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(is);

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);

                    System.out.println("br : " + br);

                    String fileContent = "";

                    String strLine;

                    while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){

                        System.out.println("strLine : " + strLine);

                        if(fileContent != null)
                        {
                            fileContent = fileContent+ strLine + "\n";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fileContent = strLine + "\n";
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("fileContent : " + fileContent);
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println("ApplicationMainServlet file name " + item.getName()+",size "+item.getSize());                       

                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you post the file upload code?

Comment: public void doProcess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

Comment: FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(); ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory); List items = upload.parseRequest(request); Iterator iter = items.iterator(); while (iter.hasNext()){ FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next(); if (!item.isFormField()) { //Output that is getting printed in logs is Val=(blank) and size=0 System.out.println("ApplicationMainServlet: name = "+item.getFieldName() + ", val = "+item.getString() + ", file size = " + item.getSize() ); request.setAttribute(name, item); //more code to follow..

Comment: Please update your original question with the code. It is unreadable as a comment. And please use the code formatting button on the edit box to format the code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `doProcess` method is being called? Have you placed any `System.out` messages elsewhere before this block of code or in it?

Also how are you declaring your form for the file upload? You need to set the `enctype` on the form to `multipart/form-data`:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadForm" action="uploadFormAction">
</form>
```

It looks like your code is mostly correct based on the [Apache documentation](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html)

```
if (!item.isFormField()) {
    System.out.println("ApplicationMainServlet: name = " + item.getFieldName() + ", val = " + item.getString() + ", file size = " + item.getSize());
}
```

A little easier to read maybe:

```
 if (!item.isFormField()) {
     String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
     String fileName = item.getName();
     long sizeInBytes = item.getSize();
     System.out.println("ApplicationMainServlet: name = " + fieldName + ", val = " + fileName + ", file size = " + sizeInBytes);
 }
```

Give that a shot and see if it works.

Comment: The problem is I am not able to send the contents of the file at the server side. I have declared the form exactly as mentioned by you. The doPost method is getting called confirmed from the sysout statements in the logs. The control goes inside the if condition (!item.isFormField()) but when I am trying to get the fileName, size or its contents it doesn't print anything. I also tried getting the inputStream on the FileItem object and tried printing the contents of the file line by line but this also fails.

Comment: I am getting the feeling that since the File contents are send to server as MIME stream thus the normal methods for retrieving file contents are not working.